# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in jQuery string

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $('#post-2233 > h2').text('Feeds / Downloads');

  $('#post-2233 > h2').after(
    '<div class="clo-column-before"> \
       <p>Please login on the right to access the content below.</p> \
       <p>Below is all the downloadable content on the website. Your account gives you access to all the items with a check mark next to it. </p> \
       <p>You can purchase additional access from your <a href="http://www.chineselearnonline.com/amember/member.php">member page</a>. If you have any problems accessing any of the content below, please <a href="http://www.chineselearnonline.com/contact-us/">contact us</a>.</p> \
     </div>'
  );

  $('#post-2233 > .entrytext').after(
    '<div class="clo-column-after"> \
       <h2>Download instructions: PC / Mac, iPhone / iPad, Android</h2> \
       <h3>PC / Mac:</h3> \
       <p>Click directly on the links to open the content. You can then download it directly from the page that opens.</p> \
       <p>Click on the iTunes logo to open the content into iTunes.</p> \
       <p>Note that the PDFs are in a zip archive that will need to extracted after download.</p>
     </div>'
  );

});
```

This is the problematic line:

```
<div class="clo-column-after"> \
```

I don't see anything strange, though.

Comment: You're missing a \ after the final <p> in the div, so the multiple line string is formatted incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that your browser is inserting end of line characters at each `\` because of the way you are splitting that multi-line string, and maybe jQuery doesn't like those characters. Just researching your questions, almost every article I saw recommended against this type of line splitting. Instead, you could do a couple of things:

**EDIT**: You are missing a `\` on the last `<p>` line. I would still consider one of the following changes, however.

1. Just use regular string concatenation:

   ```
   $('#post-2233 > .entrytext').after(
       '<div class="clo-column-after">' +
          '<h2>Download instructions: PC / Mac, iPhone / iPad, Android</h2>' +
          '<h3>PC / Mac:</h3>' +
          '<p>Click directly on the links to open the content. You can then download it directly from the page that opens.</p>' +
          '<p>Click on the iTunes logo to open the content into iTunes.</p>' +
          '<p>Note that the PDFs are in a zip archive that will need to extracted after download.</p>' +
        '</div>'
    );
   ```
2. Use templates:

   ```
   <script id="dl-instructions" type="text/template">
       <div class="clo-column-after">
          <h2>Download instructions: PC / Mac, iPhone / iPad, Android</h2>
          <h3>PC / Mac:</h3>
          <p>Click directly on the links to open the content. You can then download it directly from the page that opens.</p>
          <p>Click on the iTunes logo to open the content into iTunes.</p>
          <p>Note that the PDFs are in a zip archive that will need to extracted after download.</p>
        </div>
   </script>
   ```

   Then your jQuery `after()` call becomes:

   ```
   $('#post-2233 > .entrytext').after($('#dl-instructions').html());
   ```